# Groovy collect on a list of strings

Tags: collections, groovy

I'm trying to create a crude json outputter that takes in a list of key-value pairs and results in the appropriate json. Here's what I've got:

```
class keyValuePairs {
    private String[][] contents
    keyValuePairs(String[][] inputList) {
        contents = inputList
    }

    public String json() {
        String jsonString = '{\n'
        String[] keyVals = contents collect {jsonPair it}
        jsonString += keyVals.join(',\n') + '\n'
        jsonString += '}'
        return jsonString
    }

    String jsonPair(String[] keyVal) {
        return '  "' + keyVal[0] + '": "' + keyVal[1] + '"'
    }
}
```

My keyValuesPairs takes in a list of lists of Strings and this compiles fine, but my *contents collect {jsonPair it}* line fails with:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: auditconfigprototype.keyValuePairs.jsonPair() is applicable for argument types: (auditconfig
prototype.keyValuePairs) values: [auditconfigprototype.keyValuePairs@7fa98a66]
Possible solutions: jsonPair([Ljava.lang.String;), json()
```

I could fall back on a loop over *contents* here, but I want to take the functional approach of using *collect*. However, it seems every attempt (even trivial ones!) to do a *collect* on my *contents* list fails. Have I defined the list wrong? How should I use *collect* over a list of lists of strings?

Comment: Why don't You just use `JsonOutput` class?

Comment: Largely because I didn't know about it. I'm sure there are better tools out there, but in the interest of understanding Groovy I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in the example above. Will look into the JsonOutput class though. Thanks!

Comment: If You'd like to get a better response, add a runnable script that is failing with the mentioned exception.

Comment: Agreed, if you post a simple script with data that reproduces the problem, we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you're getting is due to this line:

```
String[] keyVals = contents collect {jsonPair it}
```

At first glance it may appear to be the equivalent of:

```
String[] keyVals = contents.collect {jsonPair it}
```

But in fact, you're getting this:

```
String[] keyVals = contents(collect() {jsonPair it})
```

## Explanation

When assigning the *keyVals* variable, the *collect()* method is being called on the *keyValuePairs* instance; on *this*.

*collect()* then iterates through a List containing a single item, the instance of *keyValuePairs*, and calls the closure with the *keyValuePairs* instance. The *jsonPair()* method is expecting a *String* array, but receives a *keyValuePairs* instead. That's what is throwing the exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: keyValuePairs.jsonPair() is applicable for argument types: (keyValuePairs) values: [keyValuePairs@63169fe0]
```

## Solution

The solution is to simply add the missing period to make the code as follows:

```
String[] keyVals = contents.collect {jsonPair it}
```

## Groovy-ier solution

As an exercise, here's another way to implement your parser.

```
def a = [
    ['firstname', 'John'],
    ['lastname', 'Doe'],
    ['language', 'Groovy']
]

class KeyValuePairs {
    def pairs

    String json() {
        new StringBuilder('{\n').with {
            append(
                pairs
                    .collect { String.format('"%s":"%s"', it[0], it[1]) }
                    .collect { "\t$it" }.join(',\n'))

            append '\n}\n'
        }.toString()
    }
}

def parser = new KeyValuePairs(pairs: a)
parser.json()
```

- This implementation uses a *List*<*List*> instead of an array because Groovy has great built-in support for them.
- By using [Groovy Beans](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-groovybeans-simpler.html), the *KeyValuePairs* instance is created without explicitly creating a boiler-plate constructor.
- A *StringBuilder* is used instead of String concatenation. Mainly because I think it makes the code look nicer.
- Since the formatting requires double-quotes, I used *String.format()*. That keeps the formatting easy to read. Note: normally I'd use a [GString](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).
- Because the formatting is applied so concisely, I did away with the *jsonPair()* method.

The first *collect()* produces an output like this:

```
[
    '"firstname":"John"', 
    '"lastname":"Doe"', 
    '"language":"Groovy"'
]
```

And the second *collect()* adds a TAB in front of the double-quotes of every pair. Finally, the *join()* builds the single String of pairs.

## Additional improvements

Another way to improve the code some more is to replace

```
it[0], it[1]
```

with

```
it.key, it.value
```

That can be done by replacing the first *collect()* with these two:

```
.collect { [['key', 'value'], it].transpose().collectEntries() }
.collect { String.format('"%s":"%s"', it.key, it.value) }
```

I hope this helps :)

## Recommended reading

- [Groovy DSL command chains](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html).
- [transpose()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose(java.util.List)) method.